# Evitar comportamiento por defecto de Sweet Alert 2

Tags: php, javascript, sweetalert2, redirección

Buen dia, tengo una consulta. Tengo una `alerta suave` que se imprime cuando se deja un campo en blanco en mi formulario.

```
echo '<script>
        swal.fire({
            type: "error",
            title: "El nombre del menu no puede estar vacio o tener caracteres especiales",
            showConfirmButton: true,
            confirmButtonText: "Cerrar",
            closeOnConfirm: false

        }).then(function(result){
            if(result.value){
                var url = window.location
                var parts = url.toString().split("/");
                var lastSegment = parts.pop() || parts.pop();
                window.location = lastSegment;

            }   

        });
        </script>';
```

La cosa es que, una vez que le doy `Cerrar` a la alerta, me redirige a la pagina original del formulario, para volver a completarlo desde cero. Aun eliminando todo el `.then({});` de la función:

```
echo '<script>
        swal.fire({
            type: "error",
            title: "El nombre del menu no puede estar vacio o tener caracteres especiales",
            showConfirmButton: true,
            confirmButtonText: "Cerrar",
            closeOnConfirm: false

        })
        </script>';
```

Quisiera saber si existe alguna forma de cerrar la alerta sin hacer absolutamente nada, es decir, dejar mi formulario tal y como está, sin necesidad de recolectar todo en variables y volver a imprimirlo en la redirección.

No se si fui claro. Espero que se haya entendido.

Comment: Yo quiero que el usuario no tenga que volver a cargar los datos que ya cargo, sino que solamente tenga que completar los que falten. Pero quería saber si puedo ahorrarme todo el proceso, ya que en el momento que la alerta se está mostrando, el formulario se ve de fondo tal cual como lo dejo el usuario. Quisiera cerrar la alerta y seguir completándolo, sin que haya una redirección.

Comment: El problema no creo que lo tengas tanto en el Sweetalert como en el momento en el que lo llamas. La función `fire()` lo único que hace es lanzar la alerta, si la lanzas en el `submit` del formulario la alerta no va a impedir que se siga ejecutando. A mi entender, lo que tendrías que tener es una función que te valide el formulario, en caso de no validado lanzar la alerta y en caso de validado lanzar el submit.

Comment: Claro, entiendo, una validación en el front. Si, suena lógico, tenia la esperanza de poder detener el envio en la misma alerta, pero se me hace que tenes razón. Muchas gracias

Comment: Date cuenta que para comprobar si los campos están o no vacíos no hace falta enviar nada al back, por eso este tipo de validaciones sobre los campos es preferible hacerlas en el front, evitando además saturar el servidor con llamadas innecesarias.